# Python String to hex

Tags: python, string, hex, wrapper

So, I've been banging my head against the wall for too long on what seems like it should be an easy data conversion. I am writing in python and passing to another module a hex value that is converted with a wrapper to c type uint_64t. the problem is I am getting this hex value via the python library argparse. When it takes in this value, for example lets use the value 0x3f, it saves it as a string. If I try to cast this as an int it throws the error:

```
"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x3f'"
```

If I create a variable hex = 0x3f however, when I print it out, it gives me the appropriate integer value. (which is great since I'm creating a uint) I am just confused how to make the conversion from string to int if a cast doesn't work. I have seen plenty of examples on turning this string into a hex value by letter (in other words take each individual character of the ascii string '0x3f' and give it a hex value) but I haven't been able to find an example of the situation I am looking for. Apologies if I'm bringing up something that has been answered time and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying that the int is in base 16:

```
>>> int("0x3f", 16)
63
```

You could also use `ast.literal_eval`, which should be able to read any string that could be used as an integer literal. You don't even have to specify a base for this one, as long as the `0x` prefix is present.

```
>>> import ast
>>> #hexadecimal
>>> ast.literal_eval("0x3f")
63
>>> #binary
>>> ast.literal_eval("0b01010")
10
>>> #octal
>>> ast.literal_eval("0712")
458
>>> #decimal
>>> ast.literal_eval("42")
42
```

Comment: That did it...I guess I need to hone my Python skills! (Although my Googling skills would probably be a better improvement!)

Answer (score 2):

`int` takes an optional second argument, which is the numerical base to use for conversion. The default is 10 (decimal conversion) but you can change it to 16 (for hex) or 0 (for automatic conversion based on prefix):

```
>>> int('0b1010', 0)
10
>>> int('0x3f', 0)
63
>>> int('0o777', 0)
511
>>> int('1234', 0)
1234
```